# How to write left join with condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Needs your help, thanks in advance !

I want to have a sql query for the requirement below

Here are 2 tables below

[image]

in table A, if level = 4, then i want to get the value from level 6 column in table B by A.Level = B.Level4 ,  and the same as when Level = 5

and the result should be below

Expected Result
AAA 46
AAA 56

Anyone can help me on this requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Comment: Poor sample data, it should include some different PK and FK values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this join will work:

```
select
       a.pk
     , b.level6
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.pk = b.fk
                   and (
                        (a.level = 4 and b.level4 = a.value)
                       or
                        (a.level = 5 and b.level5 = a.value)
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use reserved words as the column names, and both "VALUE" and "LEVEL" are reserved words.
To get your result you could use In() function when joining tables...
Try it like here:

```sql
WITH         -- Sample data
    tbl_a AS
        (   Select  'AAA' "PK", 4 "LEVEL0", 444 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select  'AAA' "PK", 5 "LEVEL0", 555 "A_VALUE" From Dual   ),
    tbl_b AS
        (   Select  'AAA' "FK", 
                    Null "LEVEL1", Null "LEVEL2", Null "LEVEL3", 
                    444 "LEVEL4", Null "LEVEL5", 46 "LEVEL6" From Dual Union All
            Select  'AAA' "FK", 
                    Null "LEVEL1", Null "LEVEL2", Null "LEVEL3", 
                    Null "LEVEL4", 555 "LEVEL5", 56 "LEVEL6" From Dual Union All
            Select  'AAA' "FK", 
                    Null "LEVEL1", Null "LEVEL2", Null "LEVEL3", 
                    777 "LEVEL4", Null "LEVEL5", 76 "LEVEL6" From Dual Union All
            Select  'AAA' "FK", 
                    Null "LEVEL1", Null "LEVEL2", Null "LEVEL3", 
                    Null "LEVEL4", 888 "LEVEL5", 86 "LEVEL6" From Dual    )
--  Main SQL
Select      a.PK, b.LEVEL6
From        tbl_a a
Left Join   tbl_b b ON( a.PK = b.FK And a.LEVEL0 In(4, 5) And a.A_VALUE In(b.LEVEL4, b.LEVEL5) )

--  R e s u l t
--  PK      LEVEL6
--  --- ----------
--  AAA         46
--  AAA         56
```

or use left join condition with where clause...

```sql
Select      a.PK, b.LEVEL6
From        tbl_a a
Left Join   tbl_b b ON( a.PK = b.FK And a.LEVEL0 In(4, 5)  )
Where       a.A_VALUE In(b.LEVEL4, b.LEVEL5)
```

... depending on your actual data you might need to use OR operator

```sql
Select      a.PK, b.LEVEL6
From        tbl_a a
Left Join   tbl_b b ON( a.PK = b.FK And a.LEVEL0 In(4, 5)  )
Where       a.A_VALUE = b.LEVEL4 OR a.A_VALUE = b.LEVEL5
```

With sample data provided all results the same.